# How to fix " 'rm' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file." error in cmd

Tags: batch-file, cmd, jira-plugin

I am new at jira-plugin and I am folowing https://developer.atlassian.com/server/framework/atlassian-sdk/create-a-plugin-skeleton/ tutorial. At the part 7 I am writing "rm -rf src/test/java/"
in cmd and getting "'rm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file." error I am using windows10. Why this command not recognized. And which command is equal to "rm -rf"

I know that rm -rf command is deleting the file which is pointed. And ı deleted with del command and it was okay.

C:\Users\osman.turalioglu\atlastutorial\adminUI>rm -rf src/test/java/
'rm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Edit : "which command is equal to "rm -rf" is specific for this question."

Comment: there is no built in command `rm` in windows. You either need to install a shell solution, or use the default windows built in functions.

Comment: If this is a folder, you can use `rmdir C:\Users\osman.turalioglu\atlastutorial\adminUI>rm -rf src/test/java/` to delete the folder in Windows Command Prompt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `del /?` for something similar in windows, as windows doesn't know `rm`.

Edit:`rd /?` might also be worth to have a look at.